# Error trying to write a value to a cell in an Excel worksheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to write my column names to an Excel worksheet using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intColumnCount; i++)
{
    strColumnName = dataPHLIP251.Columns[i].ToString();
    excelWorksheet.Cells[2, i].Value = strColumnName;
}
```

But I keep getting

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been
> thrown by the target of an invocation.'

I have tried it with and without the Value on the Cells.  How do I get around this problem?

Comment: You have to specify the library you are using for working with Excel

Comment: Are you using Excel interop? That's a very expensive way of creating Excel files. `xlsx` is a ZIP package containing XML files using a well defined format. You could create them yourself but libraries like EPPlus or NPOI allow you to load data with headers with as little as `sheets.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(myDT,true);`, `LoadFromCollection(someArray)` or even `LoadFromDataReader`

Comment: Yes I am using Excel interop.

Comment: I can add a date to a cell using   excelWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = strDate; which works fine but when I try adding the column names I get the exception.

Comment: A similar problem I once had, but for which I can't recall the library I was using, was about the column index, which started from `1` not from `0`. Just saying...

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that excel interop is not handeling cells like arrays in terms of access.
0 = out of range. Try:

```
excelWorksheet.Cells[2, i+1].Value = strColumnName;
```

If that is not the case, please provide the code where you generate the excelworksheet instance and in which line exactly the Exception is thrown.

Answer (score -1):

I think reason is still not clear with this code line. You should check the inner exception for this error which may have further explanation for causing this error.

Piece of code you shared has nothing to do with this. For better explanation please share more code.